# How to do basic authentication in codename one request

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to do a connection request. But URL i am calling is protected with basic authentication. I tried adding "authorization" header to request but it doesn't work.

How can i pass basic authentication string so that it authenticates and returns response.

Also i am not able to see "authorization" request header in network monitor.

```
ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
r.addRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic anNqb2hhfafGUiRdggVoeTY=");
```

Comment: I believe case may matter for http headers. It should be Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

This should generally work, are you sure the base 64 user/password is encoded correctly?

The network monitor doesn't show it since Java hides that particular attribute so its one of the elements we can't show within there.

Comment: I will try it when i get time i am doing some project to learn CN1.